# bitbake autoconf libevent not found

Tags: yocto, bitbake, libevent, petalinux

I'm trying to create a bitbake recipe for [trickle](https://github.com/mariusae/trickle). I can successfully build it on the target hardware if I have libevent-dev installed. However, despite including libevent (I cannot include libevent-dev) in my DEPENDS, the bitbake build fails at:

```
| checking for libevent... no
| configure: error: libevent not found
```

my complete recipe is:

```
DESCRIPTION = "trickle is a voluntary, cooperative bandwidth shaper. trickle works entirely in userland and is cross platform compatible."
LICENSE = "BSD"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE;md5=d3a2bbd2a4afe8c5578c24d761f580f8"

DEPENDS += "libevent libtirpc"

SRCREV = "09a1d955c6554eb7e625c99bf96b2d99ec7db3dc"
PV = "1.07+git09a1d95"
SRC_URI = "git://github.com/mariusae/trickle;protocol=https"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

inherit autotools

do_install() {
    install -d ${D}${bindir}
    install -m 0755 trickle ${D}${bindir}
    install -m 0755 tricklectl ${D}${bindir}
    install -m 0755 trickled ${D}${bindir}
}
```

How do I get bitbake to find libevent?

(I am more specifically using Petalinux 2020.1 which is Yocto Zeus)

Answer (score 0):

To find libevent, the `prefix` variable is used in the configuration. The default is `/usr/local`. But you need to change it to your sysroot directory. To do this you need to add a command line argument to the `configure` step:

```
EXTRA_OECONF_append="--prefix=${STAGING_EXECPREFIXDIR}"
```